# Every disk in $(S^2 \times S^1) \setminus B$ whose boundary lies in $\partial B$ separates

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology

Let $M = (S^2 \times S^1) \setminus B$, where $B$ is a small open ball in $S^2 \times S^1$. Is it true to assert that every embedded $2$-disk $D \subset M$ such that $D \cap \partial M = \partial D$ necessarily separates $M$ (i.e., represents the trivial class in $H_2(M, \partial M;\mathbb{Z})$)?

Comment: No. Choose a 2-sphere $S=S^2\times\{pt\}$ which intersects $B$ in a disk. Then $D=S\setminus B$ is a disk which does not separate $M$.

Comment: Simple! Thank you, Josh.